# The key bind I had set up in zshrc is not working in tmux session

Tags: zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I had set up a key binding for accepting autosuggest suggestions, `bindkey '^ ' autosuggest-accept`,  which works in without tmux activated, however once in tmux this doesn't work anymore.

I suspect it might have something to do with `set -g terminal-overrides "$TERM:RGB"`  in the tmux conf.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keybind` should be palced after sourcing `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` for it to be used in the tmux.

```
export TERM=tmux-256color
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
bindkey '^ ' autosuggest-accept
eval "$(starship init zsh)"
```

Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.